# How to check which tool was used to install package

Tags: command-line, upgrade, package-management, python

I am in the case of upgrading a python package. When I read the installation guide of the package, I was supposed to know what tool (pip, conda, or something else) I used to install the package at the first time. Is it possible? Cmiiw.

My question: is there a way to know which tool I used to install the package?

Answer (score 0):

- `conda list`  and  `pip list` should show what was installed with each. These will not list installs from `apt`.
- `apt` uses `/usr/lib`, `pip` and `conda` use `/usr/local/lib/`.